# Json parse much time

Tags: android, json

I am developing a map application and I parse one json file and after I take some data from this file I use the data to parse another json twenty times and I do this in one asynctask and it takes too long if I dont connect to internet on wifi(with mobil network).What is the best approach to reduce the time elapsed?Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have control over the 20 JSON's? For example, can you merge them in one JSON on the server side?

Comment: unfortunately i cant control the jsons only can read

Comment: Maybe you can use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Does it reduce the elapsed time i dont know about it.